Existance of a covering map from four circles to a bouquet of two circles
Let $R$ be the union of the four circles in the plane of radious $1$ and centered respectively at $(-3,0), (-1,0), (1,0)$ and
$(3,0)$.
Also, let $X$ be the union of the two circles of radius $1$ and centered at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.
I want to know if there exists a covering map $\rho: R \to X$.
I think the answer is no.
If there were such a covering map, than I would have an injective homomorphism
$\rho*: \pi_1(R) \to \pi_1(X)$.
I know $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ and I expect $\pi_1(R)$ to be "more complex".
Is this reasoning valid?

Have a look at Hatcher, Algebraic Topology section 1.3. It opens with examples of covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$, among which a bouquet of four circles.

Ok, thanks a lot. So $\Pi_1(R)$ is indeed $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$, but there exists an injective homomorphism from it to $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.

Why are you capitalizing $\pi$ here?

Oh sorry, @user176372 you are right. I corrected the notation.
